# Flutter - CupertinoDatePicker showing one day ahead of the today?

Tags: android, datetime, flutter, flutter-cupertino, cupertinopicker

Currently, implementing a default widget CupertinoDatePicker in my flutter app. In this date picker i want the feature that user should not be able to select the day before today. User should be able to select only the future and today's dates.

So, i am passing **"minimumDate: DateTime.now()"** property properly, but while the CupertinoDatePicker gets opened it shows me one date ahead of today. I have checked the value of **"DateTime.now()"** property. It is showing current time properly but getting issue from CupertinoDatePicker widget.

```
CupertinoDatePicker(
                    minimumDate: DateTime.now(),
                    minuteInterval: 1,
                    mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.dateAndTime,
                    onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime dateTime) {
                      print("dateTime: ${dateTime}");
                    },
)
```

Also, applied "flutter clean" command. Still facing the same issue.

Can anyone suggest a working solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick Fix,

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var now = DateTime.now();
    var today= new DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
```

then pass `today` into `minimumDate`

```
CupertinoDatePicker(
                    minimumDate: today,
                    minuteInterval: 1,
                    mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.dateAndTime,
                    onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime dateTime) {
                      print("dateTime: ${dateTime}");
                    },
                  ),
```

---

**EDIT**

Or you can use below code as suggested by @Leonard Arnold in comment

```
  minimumDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1)),
```

Output

[image]

Comment: or in one line: `minimumDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days:  1))` i think the Problem is that DateTime.now() uses also the time - so the widget can't handle a minimum time but minimum date. Thats why Ravinder's solution works and mine also :)

Comment: Yes, I found that too. the time returned by `DateTime.now()`  is the real culprit.